# Saxophone trill fingering for E6-G6

Tags: fingering, saxophone

I'm playing (rather arranging) *Wizard Wheezes* by Nicholas Hooper for our band's chamber music unit.

At the end, there is a trumpet shake from concert G to concert Bb. It would be really nice to be able to play in that range, and I am quite adept at altissimo. Anyone know a fingering for E-G on the alto saxophone?

I own a YAS-62 professional sax.

Answer (score 3):

That's a tricky one!

You could try playing a 'front E', i.e. F spatula key, C/A key, G key and octave key, and try lifting off the C/A key and G key in order to play the altissimo G. The latter is more of a tenor fingering for altissimo G than an alto fingering, but if you can get the note to sound it should work ok for the purposes of a trill.

What I can't guarantee, however, is the trumpeters being happy with you stealing their big moment!